# Formatting line spacing in docx file using python docx

Tags: python, windows, macos, docx, python-docx

I am reading in a word document using the docx library for python:

I am then making some amendments like changing colours and texts etc, which so far I have managed to do ok. However, I am working on a mac while some colleagues are working on windows and I have found that although the footer of the output document looks fine on my computer, when opening on a windows machine the spacing of the text has gone from single to double.

I am trying to specify the format to be single spacing but nothing seems to be working. This is the current attempt:

```
from docx import Document

rendered_doc = Document(output_filename)

for section in rendered_doc.sections:
        footer = section.footer
        for paragraph in footer.paragraphs:
            for run in paragraph.runs:
                run.paragraph_format.line_spacing = 1.0
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering with line spacing in a Word document when transferring between macOS and Windows systems could be related to how line spacing is handled differently by these platforms.

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt

# Open the document
rendered_doc = Document(output_filename)

# Define the desired line spacing in points (e.g., 12 points for single spacing)
line_spacing = Pt(12)

# Iterate through sections and footers
for section in rendered_doc.sections:
    footer = section.footer
    for paragraph in footer.paragraphs:
        for run in paragraph.runs:
            # Set the line spacing for the paragraph
            run.paragraph_format.line_spacing = line_spacing

# Save the modified document
rendered_doc.save(output_filename)
```